# how to remove/disable local time on Angular 2 DateTime picker

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using Angular2 DateTimePicker in my Angular app. By default it shows Date and local time. I need just date to pick by user. Below is the link from where I used this example. 
http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/datepicker/#Settings

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you implement the picker? By default according to the documentation it should only show the datePicker and hide the timePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `[settings]` object with a `format` (see possibilities in  in the link you gave)

with `[settings]="{ timePicker: false, format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}"` for instance.

Comment: thanks...that problem is solved...but it sending "Mon Oct 01 2018 10:47:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" the whole format..i just want date..

Comment: @user3361716 The value *returned by the component is probably a JavaScript Date object*. What you see is the basic `.toString()` representation of the date (just type `(new Date()).toString()` in your developer console to see that). Date objects are notoriously annoying (for a start, they are DateTime, there is no "Date only" object natively). What you *can* do is to get a standard string representation of the date by using `yourDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")` . This should be easily understood by any back-end framework.